# RubyMine can't attach to process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, debugging, rubymine

Here's my environment:

- Docker containers for DB (Postgres), Memcached and Redis
- Webpack running on the terminal
- Rails server running on another terminal

Then, in RubyMine, I execute `Attach to Process (Shift+Alt+F5)`, and select the appropriate PID from the list.

In the Run/Debugger view I can see that it is trying to attach itself, and it displays the Debugger Time-out dialog.

Over in the terminal, the server output is as follows:

```
[16061] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[16061] * Version 4.3.8 (ruby 2.7.4-p191), codename: Mysterious Traveller
[16061] * Min threads: 8, max threads: 8
[16061] * Environment: development
[16061] * Process workers: 1
[16061] * Preloading application
[16061] * Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000
[16061] * Listening on tcp://[::1]:3000
[16061] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[16061] - Worker 0 (pid: 16205) booted, phase: 0
Subprocess Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.7.2, debase 0.2.4.1, file filtering is supported) listens on 127.0.0.1:49311
17157: Ide process dispatcher notified about sub-debugger which listens on 49311

Connected from local client
17157: Starting control thread
17157: Processing in control: start
17157: Starting: running program script
[16061] - Worker 0 (pid: 17157) booted, phase: 0
[16061] ! Out-of-sync worker list, no 16205 worker
[16061] ! Out-of-sync worker list, no 16205 worker
[16061] ! Out-of-sync worker list, no 16205 worker
[16061] ! Out-of-sync worker list, no 16205 worker
```

And in RubyMine it never connects, the time out expires.

I tried also starting the server from RubyMine (Run Configuration...) but the execution is isolated and the server cannot talk to the Docker containers, which is part of its initialisation.

When using VSCode I was able to run/debug the server from the IDE and connect to the Docker containers.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: At the moment there's an issue with remote attach and breakpoints: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-28993 although it differs (it connects but doesn't hit breakpoints) so it might be worth submitting a separate issue with a project sample for reproduce

Comment: Which OS are you running Rubymine on? I've been unable to attach a debugger since upgrading MacOS to Monterey.

Comment: I'm using macOS as well, and even though I'm on Monterey now, I was on Big Sur when I posted the question.